# How to auto calculate duration in hour of 2 date and 2 time using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to count the time difference between 2 dates and 2 times in hours. User will be able to select the from date, to date , from time and to time. The problem that I'm facing now is the duration show NaN when I've selected two dates and time. I've tried by assigning a date to the `var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 "+ start); var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + end);` and the duration are able to be calculate out and display in the duration, but this is not what I want. The system that I wish to implement is giving the user to select the time and date, the system will display out the duration in hours.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#FromTime').change(function() {
    var startDate = document.getElementById('FromDate').value;
    var endDate = document.getElementById('ToDate').value;
    var start = document.getElementById('FromTime').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('ToTime').value;
    var timeStart = new Date(startDate + start);
    var timeEnd = new Date(endDate + end);
    var difference = timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime(); // This will give difference in milliseconds
    var resultInMinutes = (difference / 60000) / 60;
    var x = Math.floor(resultInMinutes);
    // var x = (Math.floor(resultInMinutes * 100) / 100).toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('duration').value = x;


  });

  $('#ToTime').change(function() {

    var startDate = document.getElementById('FromDate').value;
    var endDate = document.getElementById('ToDate').value;
    var start = document.getElementById('FromTime').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('ToTime').value;
    var timeStart = new Date(startDate + start);
    var timeEnd = new Date(endDate + end);
    var difference = timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime(); // This will give difference in milliseconds
    var resultInMinutes = (difference / 60000) / 60;
    var x = Math.floor(resultInMinutes);
    // var x = (Math.floor(resultInMinutes * 100) / 100).toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('duration').value = x;


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field  col m6 s12">
  <label for="FromDate">From Date : </label></br>
  </br>
  <input type="date" name="FromDate" id="FromDate" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
<div class="input-field  col m6 s12">
  <label for="ToDate">To Date : </label></br>
  </br>
  <input type="date" name="ToDate" id="ToDate" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
<div class="input-field col m6 s12">
  <label for="FromTime">From Time : </label></br>
  </br>
  <select id="FromTime" name="FromTime">
    <option value="00:00:00">00:00 AM</option>
    <option value="00:30:00">00:30 AM</option>
    <option value="01:00:00">01:00 AM</option>
    <option value="01:30:00">01:30 AM</option>
    <option value="02:00:00">02:00 AM</option>
    <option value="02:30:00">02:30 AM</option>
    <option value="03:00:00">03:00 AM</option>
    <option value="03:30:00">03:30 AM</option>
    <option value="04:00:00">04:00 AM</option>
    <option value="04:30:00">04:30 AM</option>
    <option value="05:00:00">05:00 AM</option>
    <option value="05:30:00">05:30 AM</option>
    <option value="06:00:00">06:00 AM</option>
    <option value="06:30:00">06:30 AM</option>
    <option value="07:00:00">07:00 AM</option>
    <option value="07:30:00">07:30 AM</option>
    <option value="08:00:00">08:00 AM</option>
    <option value="08:30:00">08:30 AM</option>
    <option value="09:00:00">09:00 AM</option>
    <option value="09:30:00">09:30 AM</option>
    <option value="10:00:00">10:00 AM</option>
    <option value="10:30:00">10:30 AM</option>
    <option value="11:00:00">11:00 AM</option>
    <option value="11:30:00">11:30 AM</option>
    <option value="12:00:00">12:00 PM</option>
    <option value="12:30:00">12:30 PM</option>
    <option value="13:00:00">13:00 PM</option>
    <option value="13:30:00">13:30 PM</option>
    <option value="14:00:00">14:00 PM</option>
    <option value="14:30:00">14:30 PM</option>
    <option value="15:00:00">15:00 PM</option>
    <option value="15:30:00">15:30 PM</option>
    <option value="16:00:00">16:00 PM</option>
    <option value="16:30:00">16:30 PM</option>
    <option value="17:00:00">17:00 PM</option>
    <option value="17:30:00">17:30 PM</option>
    <option value="18:00:00">18:00 PM</option>
    <option value="18:30:00">18:30 PM</option>
    <option value="19:00:00">19:00 PM</option>
    <option value="19:30:00">19:30 PM</option>
    <option value="20:00:00">20:00 PM</option>
    <option value="20:30:00">20:30 PM</option>
    <option value="21:00:00">21:00 PM</option>
    <option value="21:30:00">21:30 PM</option>
    <option value="22:00:00">22:00 PM</option>
    <option value="22:30:00">22:30 PM</option>
    <option value="23:00:00">23:00 PM</option>
    <option value="23:30:00">23:30 PM</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="input-field col m6 s12">
  <label for="ToTime">To Time : </label></br>
  </br>
  <select id="ToTime" name="ToTime">
    <option value="00:00:00">00:00 AM</option>
    <option value="00:30:00">00:30 AM</option>
    <option value="01:00:00">01:00 AM</option>
    <option value="01:30:00">01:30 AM</option>
    <option value="02:00:00">02:00 AM</option>
    <option value="02:30:00">02:30 AM</option>
    <option value="03:00:00">03:00 AM</option>
    <option value="03:30:00">03:30 AM</option>
    <option value="04:00:00">04:00 AM</option>
    <option value="04:30:00">04:30 AM</option>
    <option value="05:00:00">05:00 AM</option>
    <option value="05:30:00">05:30 AM</option>
    <option value="06:00:00">06:00 AM</option>
    <option value="06:30:00">06:30 AM</option>
    <option value="07:00:00">07:00 AM</option>
    <option value="07:30:00">07:30 AM</option>
    <option value="08:00:00">08:00 AM</option>
    <option value="08:30:00">08:30 AM</option>
    <option value="09:00:00">09:00 AM</option>
    <option value="09:30:00">09:30 AM</option>
    <option value="10:00:00">10:00 AM</option>
    <option value="10:30:00">10:30 AM</option>
    <option value="11:00:00">11:00 AM</option>
    <option value="11:30:00">11:30 AM</option>
    <option value="12:00:00">12:00 PM</option>
    <option value="12:30:00">12:30 PM</option>
    <option value="13:00:00">13:00 PM</option>
    <option value="13:30:00">13:30 PM</option>
    <option value="14:00:00">14:00 PM</option>
    <option value="14:30:00">14:30 PM</option>
    <option value="15:00:00">15:00 PM</option>
    <option value="15:30:00">15:30 PM</option>
    <option value="16:00:00">16:00 PM</option>
    <option value="16:30:00">16:30 PM</option>
    <option value="17:00:00">17:00 PM</option>
    <option value="17:30:00">17:30 PM</option>
    <option value="18:00:00">18:00 PM</option>
    <option value="18:30:00">18:30 PM</option>
    <option value="19:00:00">19:00 PM</option>
    <option value="19:30:00">19:30 PM</option>
    <option value="20:00:00">20:00 PM</option>
    <option value="20:30:00">20:30 PM</option>
    <option value="21:00:00">21:00 PM</option>
    <option value="21:30:00">21:30 PM</option>
    <option value="22:00:00">22:00 PM</option>
    <option value="22:30:00">22:30 PM</option>
    <option value="23:00:00">23:00 PM</option>
    <option value="23:30:00">23:30 PM</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+difference+time+hours+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor WITHOUT PHP

Answer (score 0):

Missing an output

Missing space between date and time

```
    var timeStart = new Date(`${startDate} ${start}`);
    var timeEnd = new Date(`${endDate} ${end}`);
```

I fixed invalid HTML and use jQuery for all fields

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#FromTime').change(function() {
    var startDate = $('#FromDate').val();
    var endDate = $('#ToDate').val();
    var start = $('#FromTime').val();
    var end = $('#ToTime').val();
    var timeStart = new Date(`${startDate} ${start}`);
    var timeEnd = new Date(`${endDate} ${end}`);
    var difference = timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime(); // This will give difference in milliseconds
    var resultInMinutes = (difference / 60000) / 60;
    var x = Math.floor(resultInMinutes);
    // var x = (Math.floor(resultInMinutes * 100) / 100).toFixed(0);
    console.log(x)
    $('#duration').val(x);


  });

  $('#ToTime').change(function() {

    var startDate = $('#FromDate').val();
    var endDate = $('#ToDate').val();
    var start = $('#FromTime').val();
    var end = $('#ToTime').val();
    var timeStart = new Date(`${startDate} ${start}`);
    var timeEnd = new Date(`${endDate} ${end}`);
    var difference = timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime(); // This will give difference in milliseconds
    var resultInMinutes = (difference / 60000) / 60;
    var x = Math.floor(resultInMinutes);
    // var x = (Math.floor(resultInMinutes * 100) / 100).toFixed(0);
    $('#duration').val(x);


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Duration <input id="duration"  readonly/>
<div class="input-field  col m6 s12">
  <label for="FromDate">From Date : </label></br>
  <br/>
  <input type="date" name="FromDate" id="FromDate" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
<div class="input-field  col m6 s12">
  <label for="ToDate">To Date : </label></br>
  <br/>
  <input type="date" name="ToDate" id="ToDate" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
<div class="input-field col m6 s12">
  <label for="FromTime">From Time : </label></br>
  <br/>
  <select id="FromTime" name="FromTime">
    <option value="00:00:00">00:00 AM</option>
    <option value="00:30:00">00:30 AM</option>
    <option value="01:00:00">01:00 AM</option>
    <option value="01:30:00">01:30 AM</option>
    <option value="02:00:00">02:00 AM</option>
    <option value="02:30:00">02:30 AM</option>
    <option value="03:00:00">03:00 AM</option>
    <option value="03:30:00">03:30 AM</option>
    <option value="04:00:00">04:00 AM</option>
    <option value="04:30:00">04:30 AM</option>
    <option value="05:00:00">05:00 AM</option>
    <option value="05:30:00">05:30 AM</option>
    <option value="06:00:00">06:00 AM</option>
    <option value="06:30:00">06:30 AM</option>
    <option value="07:00:00">07:00 AM</option>
    <option value="07:30:00">07:30 AM</option>
    <option value="08:00:00">08:00 AM</option>
    <option value="08:30:00">08:30 AM</option>
    <option value="09:00:00">09:00 AM</option>
    <option value="09:30:00">09:30 AM</option>
    <option value="10:00:00">10:00 AM</option>
    <option value="10:30:00">10:30 AM</option>
    <option value="11:00:00">11:00 AM</option>
    <option value="11:30:00">11:30 AM</option>
    <option value="12:00:00">12:00 PM</option>
    <option value="12:30:00">12:30 PM</option>
    <option value="13:00:00">13:00 PM</option>
    <option value="13:30:00">13:30 PM</option>
    <option value="14:00:00">14:00 PM</option>
    <option value="14:30:00">14:30 PM</option>
    <option value="15:00:00">15:00 PM</option>
    <option value="15:30:00">15:30 PM</option>
    <option value="16:00:00">16:00 PM</option>
    <option value="16:30:00">16:30 PM</option>
    <option value="17:00:00">17:00 PM</option>
    <option value="17:30:00">17:30 PM</option>
    <option value="18:00:00">18:00 PM</option>
    <option value="18:30:00">18:30 PM</option>
    <option value="19:00:00">19:00 PM</option>
    <option value="19:30:00">19:30 PM</option>
    <option value="20:00:00">20:00 PM</option>
    <option value="20:30:00">20:30 PM</option>
    <option value="21:00:00">21:00 PM</option>
    <option value="21:30:00">21:30 PM</option>
    <option value="22:00:00">22:00 PM</option>
    <option value="22:30:00">22:30 PM</option>
    <option value="23:00:00">23:00 PM</option>
    <option value="23:30:00">23:30 PM</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="input-field col m6 s12">
  <label for="ToTime">To Time : </label></br>
  <br/>
  <select id="ToTime" name="ToTime">
    <option value="00:00:00">00:00 AM</option>
    <option value="00:30:00">00:30 AM</option>
    <option value="01:00:00">01:00 AM</option>
    <option value="01:30:00">01:30 AM</option>
    <option value="02:00:00">02:00 AM</option>
    <option value="02:30:00">02:30 AM</option>
    <option value="03:00:00">03:00 AM</option>
    <option value="03:30:00">03:30 AM</option>
    <option value="04:00:00">04:00 AM</option>
    <option value="04:30:00">04:30 AM</option>
    <option value="05:00:00">05:00 AM</option>
    <option value="05:30:00">05:30 AM</option>
    <option value="06:00:00">06:00 AM</option>
    <option value="06:30:00">06:30 AM</option>
    <option value="07:00:00">07:00 AM</option>
    <option value="07:30:00">07:30 AM</option>
    <option value="08:00:00">08:00 AM</option>
    <option value="08:30:00">08:30 AM</option>
    <option value="09:00:00">09:00 AM</option>
    <option value="09:30:00">09:30 AM</option>
    <option value="10:00:00">10:00 AM</option>
    <option value="10:30:00">10:30 AM</option>
    <option value="11:00:00">11:00 AM</option>
    <option value="11:30:00">11:30 AM</option>
    <option value="12:00:00">12:00 PM</option>
    <option value="12:30:00">12:30 PM</option>
    <option value="13:00:00">13:00 PM</option>
    <option value="13:30:00">13:30 PM</option>
    <option value="14:00:00">14:00 PM</option>
    <option value="14:30:00">14:30 PM</option>
    <option value="15:00:00">15:00 PM</option>
    <option value="15:30:00">15:30 PM</option>
    <option value="16:00:00">16:00 PM</option>
    <option value="16:30:00">16:30 PM</option>
    <option value="17:00:00">17:00 PM</option>
    <option value="17:30:00">17:30 PM</option>
    <option value="18:00:00">18:00 PM</option>
    <option value="18:30:00">18:30 PM</option>
    <option value="19:00:00">19:00 PM</option>
    <option value="19:30:00">19:30 PM</option>
    <option value="20:00:00">20:00 PM</option>
    <option value="20:30:00">20:30 PM</option>
    <option value="21:00:00">21:00 PM</option>
    <option value="21:30:00">21:30 PM</option>
    <option value="22:00:00">22:00 PM</option>
    <option value="22:30:00">22:30 PM</option>
    <option value="23:00:00">23:00 PM</option>
    <option value="23:30:00">23:30 PM</option>
  </select>
</div>
```